# WinSCP - Interactive execution of command

Tags: winscp

I use to login to Unix server using `dzdo` command

```
dzdo su - kit 
<typing a password>
```

where `kit` is my login.

Is WinSCP able to send a password (or any other string) to remote shell?

Comment: it seems I have just found an answer in documentation   "...The command must not require user input."  :(

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP is file transfer client, not a terminal client.

To execute remote commands, use a terminal client, like PuTTY or Plink.

---

If you actually want to gain root privileges for your file transfer (SFTP) session, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su).